# NSOutlineView: Cells are initially too narrow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I did a little demo to isolate a problem I faced in a Project.

When I start the Application, the Cells of the `NSOutlineView` are too narrow for the text:

[image: Initial View]

Then I resize the window with the mouse, making it even narrower than the contents of the `NSOutlineView`:

[image: Narrowed View]

When I now enlarge the window again, the problem is cured. From now on the outline works as expected:

[image: Re-Enlarged View]

This is the main method of my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0., 0., 400., 300.);
    NSUInteger styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask;
    _mainWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:styleMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    _mainWindow.title = @"Outline";

    NSScrollView *leftScrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] init];
    leftScrollView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
    leftScrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = NO;
    leftScrollView.drawsBackground = NO;
    leftScrollView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
    _mainWindow.contentView = leftScrollView;

    NSOutlineView *outlineView = [[NSOutlineView alloc] init];
    NSTableColumn *outlineColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Menu Item"];
    [outlineView addTableColumn:outlineColumn];
    outlineView.outlineTableColumn = outlineColumn;
    outlineView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList;
    outlineView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
    outlineView.headerView = nil;
    _outlineDataSourceAndDelegate = [[MROutlineDataSourceAndDelegate alloc] init];
    outlineView.dataSource = _outlineDataSourceAndDelegate;
    outlineView.delegate = _outlineDataSourceAndDelegate;
    leftScrollView.documentView = outlineView;

    [_mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
}
```

Can anyone please explain that odd behavior?

Comment: I already tried using `initWithFrame` instead of `init` with a reasonable large rectangle for both the scroll view and the outline view. That didn't change anything. I also tried setting `outlineView.frame` before adding it to the scroll view, afterwards and after `makeKeyAndOrderFront`. That was not helpful, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above was not clean enough for me, so I continued playing around. Now I am pleased: I added a listener to the scroll view that resizes the width of the outline view to be the same as the scroll view. No more need to set the width of the outline column in advance. This is important, if the width is not known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether that is the most elegant solution, but at least it works. I added the following single line after creating the `NSTableColumn`:

```
    outlineColumn.width = SIDEBAR_WIDTH_DEFAULT;
```

That's it. Took me almost a day to figure out :(